# Cache.EffectivePrivateBytesLimit set to '-1' even though value specified in web.config

Tags: asp.net, memory, httpruntime.cache

I have entered the value in web.config for the cache size as below:

```
<system.web>
   <caching>

      <cache privateBytesLimit="10000000" privateBytesPollTime="00:01:00" />

   </caching>
```

However, when I check the value of  `System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache.EffectivePrivateBytesLimit`, it is set to `-1`.  Any ideas why?

Comment: I noticed that is was -1 when running in my development environment, but had some large value when running in IIS.